# como buscar fraciones de una palabra dentro de un arreglo en angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

Con el siguiente codigo puedo filtrar la informacion de un arreglo siempre y cuando los parametros enviado sean igual a lo evaluado dentro del arreglo, ahora bien lo que necesito realizar es poder buscar dentro del arreglo por una fraccion de alguna palabra eje

dentro de las informaciones que tiene el arreglo guardo el nombre de cada representante,
imaginemos que tenemos varios representantes con su primer nombre juan, deseo que al pasarle la palabra juan me traiga todo los representante con este nombre

```
//asignando las informaciones del localstorage al arreglo

this.signinmodel = this.localStorageService.getData('TablaRepresentantes') || [];
//Filtrar por nombre
this.data = this.signinmodel.filter(
  item => item.repCodigo === this.repcodigo && 
  item.repClave === this.repclave
);
```

el arreglo que tengo es el siguiente

```
stringArray: any[] = [
    { title: "Banana verde", color: "verde" },
    { title: "Banana marron", color: "podrida" },
    { title: "Banana amarilla", color: "Yellow" },
    { title: "Banana roj ", color: "no se puede comer" },
    { title: "Apple", color: "Red" },
    { title: "Guava", color: "Green" },
    { title: "Strawberry", color: "Red" }
  ];
```

Deseo que al filtrar el arreglo por la palabra Bana me traiga toda la informacion referente a esa fraccion de informacion sin importa donde se encuetre ese nombre.

he tratado con este otro codigo

```
 // Función para verificar si algún string en el array contiene una fracción específica
  arrayContainsFractionOfString(arr: string[], fraction: string): boolean {
    return arr.some(element => element.includes(fraction));
  }

  // Ejemplo de uso
  verificarFraccion() {
    const fraccionARevisar = 'na';
    const contieneFraccion = this.arrayContainsFractionOfString(this.stringArray, fraccionARevisar);

    if (contieneFraccion) {
      console.log(`El array contiene una fracción de "${fraccionARevisar}"`);
    } else {
      console.log(`El array no contiene una fracción de "${fraccionARevisar}"`);
    }
  }
```

pero no he podido lograr hacer el filtro ya que me sale el siguiente error

```
core.mjs:8400 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: element.includes is not a function
TypeError: element.includes is not a function
    at client.page.ts:227:40
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at ClientPage.arrayContainsFractionOfString (client.page.ts:227:16)
    at ClientPage.verificarFraccion (client.page.ts:233:35)
    at ClientPage.ngOnInit (client.page.ts:65:11)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2434:22)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2403:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2354:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10341:21)
    at detectChangesInternal (core.mjs:11529:9)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
    at zone.js:1278:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at core.mjs:23896:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23896:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24197:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
```

Resultado esperado

```
stringArray: any[] = [
    { title: "Banana verde", color: "verde" },
    { title: "Banana marron", color: "podrida" },
    { title: "Banana amarilla", color: "Yellow" },
    { title: "Banana roj ", color: "no se puede comer" },
   
  ];
```

el arreglo filtrado nada mas con las informaciones correspondiente a la cadena de catacteres

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de la lista `signinmodel ` y el resultado esperado al buscar por X palabra

Comment: Listo @Yussef acabo de modificar la pregunta incluiyendo las informaciones solictada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es que `some` es como decir: "Existe algun elemento que cumple esta condición?" y la respuesta es `true` o `false`

La función que tu estas buscando es [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), que justamente filtra los resultandos, entregados los items que cumplen la condición. En tu ejemplo que si usas filter estas usando un `&&` en cuyo caso la palabra debe estar si o si en los 2 campos, por lo que creo que deberías usar un `||`

Para ver si un texto está contenido de otro se usa `includes`, pero ojo que distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Esto se puede solventar transformando todo a mayúsculas o minúsculas con las funciones `toUpperCase` y `toLowerCase` respectivamente.

```js
const stringArray = [
    { title: "Banana verde", color: "verde" },
    { title: "Banana marron", color: "podrida" },
    { title: "Banana amarilla", color: "Yellow" },
    { title: "Banana roj ", color: "no se puede comer" },
    { title: "Apple", color: "Red" },
    { title: "Guava", color: "Green" },
    { title: "Strawberry", color: "Banana roja" },
    { title: "banana", color: "xxxxx" }
  ];

//solo en los title
const resp1 = stringArray.filter(i => i.title.includes("Banana"));
console.log(resp1);

//En title o en color
const resp2 = stringArray.filter(i => i.title.includes("Banana") || i.color.includes("Banana") );
console.log(resp2);

//En cualquier campo si el objeto tuviera muchos
const resp3 = stringArray.filter(i => Object.values(i).some(x=>x.includes("Banana")));
console.log(resp3);

//Sin distinguir entre mayusculas y minusculas
function compare(frase,palabra){
  return frase.toLowerCase().includes(palabra.toLowerCase());
}
const resp4 = stringArray.filter(i => compare(i.title,"BaNaNA"));
console.log(resp4);
```

Comment: excelente me ayudo bastante y la explicacion fue bastante clara y sencilla